# Django-Rest-Auth Reset Password via email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm attempting to implement a *Forgot Password* button, utilizing the url `/rest_auth/pasword/reset`.

My assumption, from reading the [docs](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html#basic) on this endpoint, is that you only need to pass an `email` to the endpoint, and then the reset email will be sent, prompting the user to reset their password.

The issue is, this flow only works when the user is actually logged in, thus when the session has a valid token key to send back to the server.

If the user forgets their password, they obviously won't be logged in, and thus won't have a token to send back to the server. This is the error I get when trying to post to the endpoint with just the email and no token header.

`{"detail":"Invalid token header. No credentials provided."}`

I didn't think that we should need to include a token in the header because that defeats the purpose. Am I misunderstanding how this endpoint is supposed to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Found out I was still sending an `Authorization` header by accident with an empty token when calling endpoints that didn't need a token key.